# Does player age have any effect on the game?

Tags: mischief-makers

Mischief Makers is an older Nintendo 64 game from 1997. 
[image]

When a player sets up a save they are asked to input a player name and the player's age. I've played the game with various different ages (01, 13, 21, 99), and have never noticed a significant difference in game play or difficulty. Is there a point to asking for the age of the player? Does the age of the player have any effect on the game at all, if it does what is that effect?

Comment: I feel like you missed the opportunity for a [much more amusing title](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/2196/106152). I'm tempted to suggest a retitle to `Will I make more mischief if I'm older?`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Age affects only the ending. In fact, only one screen, right before the credits.

Sooo... spoilers ! (very minor, but still one of the last images of the game - from [vgmuseum.com](http://www.vgmuseum.com/end/n64/a/mischief.htm))

---

> If your age is 15 or less :
>
>  [image: <=15]
>
>  If your age is 16 or more :
>
>  [image: >=16]

Comment: Clearly those shoulderpads aren't appropriate for an underaged audience

Comment: @ChargerIIC. I thought about target audience too, but when you look more closely, you'll notice the different pictures are of the same character at a different age. The 15- picture looks like a 10-12 year-old girl, while the 16+ one looks more like a 18-24 year-old. I think they wanted to make many more pictures depending on the player's age, but couldn't do more than 2 (maybe because of limitations, budget, or whatever).